# Multiple wildcards not working in centos 7

Tags: bash, centos, centos7

In Ubuntu I could run `truncate -s 0 /var/log/*/* &> /dev/null` to clear all the log files in /var/log/ dir and directories under that in one command

But in centos, it doesn't work. Instead I have to run `truncate -s 0 /var/log/* &> /dev/null ; truncate -s 0 /var/log/*/* &> /dev/null` to clear the /var/log/ dir and then clear the dirs under /var/log/

Comment: Only the second behaviour seems correct to me. To do what you describe, you'd need something like Bash's `globstar` shell option and use `**/*`, not `*/*`.

Comment: Please add your tuncate version, bash version, Ubuntu version, output of `shopt | grep glob` and `echo $-` to your question.